# Возвращается ли селектор?

Tags: jquery

Возвращается ли селектор (`#box1`, `#box2` или `#box3`), если сработало условие, при уточнении поиска с помощью перечисления, например, `$(".primer", "#box1, #box2, #box3")`?

Перебираю элементы с помощью `.each`, например, так:

```
$(".primer", "#box1, #box2, #box3").each(function(i){ любое условие, если элемент ему соответствует, сообщаем об этом });
```

Вопрос. Возвращает ли `.each`, в каком из `#box1`, или `#box2`, или `#box3` сработало условие, если идет перебор внутри `.each`?

Если нет, то как это выяснить, кроме `parent()`, `parents()` и `closest()`, как-то более по умному?

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант

```
$(".primer", "#box1, #box2, #box3").each(function(i){ 
    switch ($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'box1': ....
        ......
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Определить просто: назначить класс боксам и выбирать родителя с этим классом.

```
$('.boxN .primer').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.boxN').attr('id');
});
```

А насчет возвращается или нет - это вы проверьте сами. =)

Comment: Я так и делаю через .closest (смотрите внимательнее вопрос), предположил, что есть более эффективный способ, вот и спросил 

Comment: Похоже, что никак. Разве что можно придумать свою функцию.